# Powershell - Write JSON with column and row to MSSQL DB

Tags: json, powershell, datatable

I have the json output in powershell as below type

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                                             
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                                             
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

with content as below.

```
{
    "columns":  [
                    {
                        "name":  "@timestamp",
                        "type":  "datetime"
                    },
                    {
                        "name":  "first.hostname",
                        "type":  "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "name":  "username",
                        "type":  "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "name":  "payload",
                        "type":  "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "name":  "domain",
                        "type":  "text"
                    }
                ],
    "rows":  [
                 [
                     "2021-06-23T07:53:17.294Z",
                     "Name1",
                     "User1",
                     "Message",
                     "Domain"
                 ],
                 [
                    "2021-06-23T07:53:17.294Z",
                    "Name1",
                    "User1",
                    "Message",
                    "Domain"
                 ]
             ]
}
```

I need to be able to write this column and row mapping to a MSSQL DB. I am familiar with writing a datatable to DB in powershell. The part where i am struggling is to convert this content into a proper datatable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `[DataTable]`, then use the values from the `columns` array to define the columns, and the values from `rows` to populate the table:

```
# Convert JSON to a custom object
$tableDefinition = $json |ConvertFrom-Json

# Define type mappings
$typeMap = @{
  datetime = [datetime]
  text     = [string]
}

# Create a datatable to hold the data
$dataTable = [System.Data.DataTable]::new()

# Create column definitions from JSON
foreach($column in $tableDefinition.columns){
  [void]$dataTable.Columns.Add($column.name, $typeMap[$column.type])
}

# Populate table with rows
foreach($row in $tableDefinition.rows){
  [void]$dataTable.Rows.Add($row)
}
```

Comment: this worked and now i have the data in the DB. Awesome, thanks Mathias.

Wish I can upvote it, but i do not have enough reputation :(

Comment: @DelphinSA That's great! You can mark my answer "accepted" by clicking the checkmark on the left :-)